# Cannot read string from file with fscanf() in c

Tags: c, scanf

I tried to make code that read struct contents from existing file but it doesn't shows up human readable contents

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Student{
    char studentName[30];
    char studentLast[30];
};

int main()
{
    struct Student s1,s2;
    FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (file==NULL){
        printf("Error Reading students");
        return 1;
    }
    while(1){
        int cnt=fscanf(file, "%s\t%s\t\n", &s1.studentName, &s1.studentLast);
        if (cnt == -1)
            break;
        printf(file, "%s\t%s\t\n", s1.studentName, s1.studentLast);
    }

    fclose(file);
    return  0;
}
```

I tried thousand times to change them around nothing works at all :/

Comment: where are you using `fread` in your code ?

Comment: I see a `fscanf()`, `fopen()` , `printf()` and a `fclose()` but no `fread()` . I hope I'm not going blind..... unless, the OP just posted it wrong

Comment: `test.txt` contents of? Or how it was created?

Comment: test.txt is existed file but this code doesn't read the contents properly and show them as results.

Comment: Try `int cnt=fscanf(file, "%s\t%s\t\n", s1.studentName, s1.studentLast);` It should solve your problem.

Comment: I guess I need to make that appointment with the optician

Comment: You are reading _and_ writing to the same `file`.  That can't end well.

Comment: Learn to diagnose a problem: use `fgets()` to read a line and then look at it in the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Remove file from this line:

```
    printf(file, "%s\t%s\t\n", s1.studentName, s1.studentLast);
```

[printf()](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatted-Output-Functions.html) expects a const char *template as its first argument.

Once removed, your code works.

Answer (score 1):

First, as underlined by @MarianoMacchi , the compiler complains about `printf(file, "%s\t%s\t\n", s1.studentName, s1.studentLast);` which should be either `printf("%s\t%s\t\n", s1.studentName, s1.studentLast);` or `fprintf(file_open_with_w_or_a,"%s\t%s\t\n", s1.studentName, s1.studentLast);`, but i guess this line is added to debug, or provide a minimal example.

Athoner issue is `int cnt=fscanf(file, "%s\t%s\t\n", &s1.studentName, &s1.studentLast);` which should be :

```
int cnt=fscanf(file, "%29s\t%29s\t\n", s1.studentName, s1.studentLast);
```

[`fscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) needs the pointer to the data to be read. So, in case of an integer, it is : `int a;fscanf(file,"%d",&a);`. For a string, it needs the pointer to the first character :

```
char s[42];
fscanf(file,"%41s",&s[0]);
```

or equivalently :

```
char s[42];
fscanf(file,"%41s",s);`.
```

The maximum number of items to be read may be added, to avoid undefined behavior in case of large inputs. [`fscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) returns the number of items successfully read, so the loop may be exited as `cnt!=2`.

I suggest the following loop :

```
while(1){
    int cnt=fscanf(file, "%29s\t%29s\t\n", s1.studentName, s1.studentLast);
    if (cnt != 2)
        break;
    printf("%s\t%s\t\n", s1.studentName, s1.studentLast);
}
```